# ArrayList iteration with Streams

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have list of lists. i need to extract items from these lists based on index and make it individual arraylist. I tried doing it by adding

```
List<List<String>> multilist = new ArrayList<>();

List<List<String>> totalRecords= totalRecordsList;

List<String> targetList = totalRecords.stream().filter(e ->
     e.get(index)!=null).flatMap(List::stream) .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

multilist.add(targetList);
```

But still inside list of lists rather than storing as individual arraylist objects, it is combining all the items. Can you please correct wherever i am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `List<List<String> = totalRecords;` this is not syntactically accurate

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your current code snippet has many syntax errors that make it difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Be sure to include a class and method around your code so that we can just copy and paste it to compile ourselves.

Comment: It should be List<List<String> totalRecords = totalRecordsList;

Comment: You are still missing a closing `>`.

Comment: `flatMap` does just that, it flattens the list of lists into a one dimensional list. remove that method call.

Comment: Do you mean `map(e -> e.get(index))` instead of the flatMap?

Answer (score 1):

This operation:

```
.flatMap(List::stream)
```

flattens everything in the input lists into a stream.

If you just want to take the `index`-th element of each list, replace this with:

```
.map(e -> e.get(index))
```

Overall:

```
totalRecords.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.get(index)!=null)
    .map(e -> e.get(index))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
```

You can avoid repeating the get by reversing the filter and map:

```
totalRecords.stream()
    .map(e -> e.get(index))
    .filter(Object::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
```